E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock. It is held by process 36194 (unattended-upgr)
Tried to install GoBuster ,but got this error, and tried:
sudo killall apt apt-get
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
No luck so far, and am looking for a way to not have my dpkg get hung up on a singular process.
SPECS
VM-Hyper-V
OS-Ubuntu 22.04 w/ quick create
MATE Terminal
RAM-32Gb

Is there some kind of upgrade or other install already going?

it says i have ~400 updates. not sure if those are running or not.

There would never normally be 400 updates in process in a Ubuntu OS. What is the version of the Ubuntu OS you are using?

22.04 but I was trying to install GoBuster from the command prompt. The dpkg usually gets really hung up when I'm installing new tools, but I'm also trying to use nmap and get functions for classes while tools are installing. Would I just have to wait it out?

Yes if you wont let it finish it wont work.

Is there a way I can see what task the dpkg is on, and how long it might take?

Not that I know of.

You should never remove the lock file.  Instead, use ps to examine the process holding the lock and possibly kill it.

If you really have ~400 updates, then something is very wrong. Put your install on hold until you have investigated and fixed your system.

Because you have so many pending updates ( ~400) it's not worth gambling on ending up with possibly up to 400 borked packages. If this happened, it would take a long time to sort out the package management mess.
The sensible course of action is to wait it out and let the software updating process complete by itself. The terminal will print an error message or a warning message if anything unexpected happens while you are waiting for the software to finish updating.
